# Most recent previous business day in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I need to subtract *business days* from the current date.

I currently have some code which needs always to be running on the most recent business day. So that may be today if we're Monday thru Friday, but if it's Saturday or Sunday then I need to set it back to the Friday before the weekend. I currently have some pretty **clunky** code to do this:

```
 lastBusDay = datetime.datetime.today()
 if datetime.date.weekday(lastBusDay) == 5:      #if it's Saturday
     lastBusDay = lastBusDay - datetime.timedelta(days = 1) #then make it Friday
 elif datetime.date.weekday(lastBusDay) == 6:      #if it's Sunday
     lastBusDay = lastBusDay - datetime.timedelta(days = 2); #then make it Friday
```

Is there a better way?

Can I tell timedelta to work in weekdays rather than calendar days for example?

Comment: What about holidays?

Comment: Here's a snippet from dzzone that might help you out: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/9173

Comment: yeah I'm already taking care of those: my database always backfills holidays as long as they fall on a weekday. But I agree, holidays in general are also an issue. I mean I could start getting fancy and use the sckits.timeseries but really I want something simpler.

Comment: hello, i'm late to the party, sorry. one simpler thing OP could have done is checking whether datetime.date.weekday(lastBusDay) >=5 instead of checking Saturday and Sunday separatedly.  but yeah .. there are other better answer below, anyway.

Comment: Saturday and Sunday are not generic enough, as in some countries, e.g. Israel, the work week is Sun-Thu.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Use pandas!

```
import datetime
# BDay is business day, not birthday...
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

today = datetime.datetime.today()
print(today - BDay(4))
```

Since today is Thursday, Sept 26, that will give you an output of:

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 20, 14, 8, 4, 89761)
```

Comment: The most recent pandas release (0.14.0) supports holiday calendars too

Comment: Installing pandas adds 233M to vps.  So I reinvented a barebones wheel.

Comment: @EB https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-holiday

Answer (score 28):

If you want to skip US holidays as well as weekends, this worked for me (using pandas 0.23.3):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
US_BUSINESS_DAY = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
july_5 = pd.datetime(2018, 7, 5)
result = july_5 - 2 * US_BUSINESS_DAY # 2018-7-2
```

To convert to a python date object I did this:

```
result.to_pydatetime().date()
```

Answer (score 18):

Maybe this code could help:

```
lastBusDay = datetime.datetime.today()
shift = datetime.timedelta(max(1,(lastBusDay.weekday() + 6) % 7 - 3))
lastBusDay = lastBusDay - shift
```

The idea is that on Mondays yo have to go back 3 days, on Sundays 2, and 1 in any other day.

The statement `(lastBusDay.weekday() + 6) % 7` just re-bases the Monday from 0 to 6.

Really don't know if this will be better in terms of performance.

Answer (score 13):

There seem to be several options if you're open to installing extra libraries.

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170418210927/http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Python/comp.lang.python/2004-09/3758.html) describes a way of defining workdays with [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
import datetime
from dateutil import rrule
alpha=datetime.date(2004, 01, 01) # change to accept input
omega=datetime.date(2004, 02, 01) # change to accept input
dates=rrule.rruleset() # create an rrule.rruleset instance
dates.rrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.FREQ_DAILY, dtstart=alpha, until=omega))
             # this set is INCLUSIVE of alpha and omega
dates.exrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.FREQ_DAILY,
                        byweekday=(rrule.SA, rrule.SU),
                        dtstart=alpha))
# here's where we exclude the weekend dates
print len(list(dates)) # there's probably a faster way to handle this
```

BusinessHours lets you custom-define your list of holidays, etc., to define when your working hours (and by extension working days) are.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BusinessHours/

Comment: nice one Alison. Still not very simple though unfortunately. I'm going to go your route though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Defining business days across all cultures is unlikely to be simple enough a problem to get included in the standard library.

Comment: A valid point, as indeed my application is for financial markets, and Egypt and Israel are open on Sunday.

Comment: Does anyone even use BuinessHours? Within 1 minute I discovered that line 87 should read `self.worktiming[1]` (missing **self**) and line 51 should read `extradays` (missing **s**). The source code itself looks pretty poor with semicolons scattered throughout.

Answer (score 11):

**DISCLAMER:** I'm the author...

I wrote a package that does exactly this, business dates calculations. You can use custom week specification and holidays.

I had this exact problem while working with financial data and didn't find any of the available solutions particularly easy, so I wrote one.

Hope this is useful for other people.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/business_calendar/

Comment: thanks a lot, your library worked perfectly for me. Maybe you should add on your documentation that your library support negative days if you want to subtract days, and that it is up on pip

Comment: Hey, I know this might not be the best way to reach you but I just wanted to report an issue I was having with your business_calendar module.  I set up a calendar with US federal holidays: ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-19',
            '2015-02-16', '2015-05-25',
            '2015-07-03', '2015-09-07',
            '2015-10-12', '2015-11-11',
            '2015-11-26', '2015-12-25'] then tried to calculate the difference between datetime(2015, 1, 16, 15, 28, 40) and datetime(2015, 1, 23, 11, 58, 0) but it consistently returns -1.  Stripping the h/m/s from the datetimes results (correctly) in 4.

Comment: Actually upon further testing certain date comparisons just block, with no apparent reason, never seeming to return a result. In my above example attempting to compare datetime(2015, 1, 16) with datetime(2015, 1, 25) leads to such a block, with or without explicitly setting any holidays. Upon investigation this occurs when the date2 parameter happens to be a date that is not a work day.

Answer (score 9):

If somebody is looking for solution respecting holidays (without any huge library like  pandas), try this function:

```
import holidays
import datetime


def previous_working_day(check_day_, holidays=holidays.US()):
    offset = max(1, (check_day_.weekday() + 6) % 7 - 3)
    most_recent = check_day_ - datetime.timedelta(offset)
    if most_recent not in holidays:
        return most_recent
    else:
        return previous_working_day(most_recent, holidays)

check_day = datetime.date(2020, 12, 28)
previous_working_day(check_day)
```

which produces:

```
datetime.date(2020, 12, 24)
```

Answer (score 7):

[`timeboard`](https://github.com/mmamaev/timeboard) package does this.

Suppose your date is 04 Sep 2017. In spite of being a Monday, it was a holiday in the US (the Labor Day). So, the most recent business day was Friday, Sep 1.

```
>>> import timeboard.calendars.US as US
>>> clnd = US.Weekly8x5()
>>> clnd('04 Sep 2017').rollback().to_timestamp().date()
datetime.date(2017, 9, 1)
```

In UK, 04 Sep 2017 was the regular business day, so the most recent business day was itself.

```
>>> import timeboard.calendars.UK as UK
>>> clnd = UK.Weekly8x5()
>>> clnd('04 Sep 2017').rollback().to_timestamp().date()
datetime.date(2017, 9, 4)
```

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of timeboard.

Answer (score 4):

For the pandas usecase, I found the following to be quite useful and compact, although not completely readable:

Get most recent previous business day:

```py
In [2]: datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 30) + BDay(1) - BDay(1)  # Saturday
Out[2]: Timestamp('2019-11-29 00:00:00')


In [3]: datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29) + BDay(1) - BDay(1)  # Friday
Out[3]: Timestamp('2019-11-29 00:00:00')
```

In the other direction, simply use:

```py
In [4]: datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 30) + BDay(0)  # Saturday
Out[4]: Timestamp('2019-12-02 00:00:00')

In [5]: datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29) + BDay(0)  # Friday
Out[5]: Timestamp('2019-11-29 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give a generator of working days, of course without holidays, stop is datetime.datetime object. If you need holidays just make additional argument with list of holidays and check with 'IFology' ;-)

```
def workingdays(stop, start=datetime.date.today()):
    while start != stop:
        if start.weekday() < 5:
            yield start
        start += datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Later on you can count them like

```
workdays = workingdays(datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 8))
len(list(workdays))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like:

```
lastBusDay = datetime.datetime.today()
if datetime.date.weekday(lastBusDay) not in range(0,5):
    lastBusDay = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 def getNthBusinessDay(startDate, businessDaysInBetween):
    currentDate = startDate
    daysToAdd = businessDaysInBetween
    while daysToAdd > 0:
        currentDate += relativedelta(days=1)
        day = currentDate.weekday()
        if day < 5:
            daysToAdd -= 1

    return currentDate
```

Answer (score 1):

When I am writing this answer, today is Friday in USA so next business day shall be Monday, in the meantime yesterday is [thanksgiving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanksgiving_(United_States)) holiday so previous business day should be Wednesday

So today date of **Friday, November 24, 2022**, is a perfect time to get the previous, current and next business days.

By having trial and error, I could only find the correct output by combining the method as below:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar


US_BUSINESS_DAY = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

TODAY = datetime.today() - 1 * US_BUSINESS_DAY
YESTERDAY = (datetime.today() - timedelta(max(1,(TODAY.weekday() + 6) % 7 - 3))) - 1 * US_BUSINESS_DAY
TOMORROW = TODAY + BDay(1)

DAY_NAME = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday']

BUSINESS_DATE = "[Previous (" + DAY_NAME[YESTERDAY.weekday()] + "):'" + YESTERDAY.strftime('%y%m%d') 
BUSINESS_DATE += "', Current (" + DAY_NAME[TODAY.weekday()] + "):'" + TODAY.strftime('%y%m%d') 
BUSINESS_DATE +=  "', Next (" + DAY_NAME[TOMORROW.weekday()] + "):'" + TOMORROW.strftime('%y%m%d') + "']"

print_("Business Date USA = ", BUSINESS_DATE)
```

Output:

> **Business Date USA = [Previous (Wednesday):'221123', Current (Friday):'221125', Next (Monday):'221128']**

Answer (score 1):

Getting the most recent business day:

```
pd.bdate_range(end=(pd.to_datetime('today').date()), periods=1)[0])
```

OR in case you want it as a 'datetime.date' type:

```
(pd.bdate_range(end=(pd.to_datetime('today').date()), periods=1)[0]).date()
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer actually gives an incorrect result because today - BDay(0) rounds forward to Monday during the weekend instead of back to Friday like the question states.  What you'd want is BusinessDay().rollback() which rolls back to the prior business day (the accepted answer matches BusinessDay().rollforward() logic).

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()
prior_bday = pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay().rollback(today)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this does not yield the desired result.
``today = datetime.datetime.today()
prior_bday = pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay().rollback(today)

print(today)
print(prior_bday)
2023-12-28 08:37:29.225472
2023-12-28 08:37:29.225472``

Answer (score 1):

Get first day of month, last day of month and last business day of previous month if last day falls on weekend Saturday/Sunday

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
day = datetime(2023, 1, 10)
#last day of (n) previous month (n=months)
#n = 0 -- for current month
n=1
lastDayMonth = ((day - relativedelta(months=n) + relativedelta(day=31)).date());
#First day of previous month (n=months=1)
firstDayMonth = ((day - relativedelta(months=n) + relativedelta(day=1)).date());
print("Last Day of Month - "+ str(lastDayMonth))
print("First Day of Month - "+ str(firstDayMonth))
#Last business day (Friday) of prev (n) month (n=months=1)
lastBusDay = (lastDayMonth - timedelta(max(1,(lastDayMonth.weekday() + 6) % 7 - 3))) if lastDayMonth.weekday() in (5,6) else lastDayMonth
print("Last Business Day of Month - " + str(lastBusDay))
print()
--- Output
Last Day of Month - 2022-12-31
First Day of Month - 2022-12-01
Last Business Day of Month - 2022-12-30
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it too complicated)

```
lastBusDay = datetime.datetime.today()
timedelta_tuple = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2)
lastBusDay = lastBusDay + datetime.timedelta(days = timedelta_tuple[lastBusDay.weekday()])
```

Answer (score 0):

another simplify version

```py
lastBusDay = datetime.datetime.today()
wk_day = datetime.date.weekday(lastBusDay)
if wk_day > 4:      #if it's Saturday or Sunday
    lastBusDay = lastBusDay - datetime.timedelta(days = wk_day-4) #then make it Friday
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution irrespective of different jurisdictions having different holidays:

If you need to find the right id within a table, you can use this snippet. The Table model is a sqlalchemy model and the dates to search from are in the field day.

```py
def last_relevant_date(db: Session, given_date: date) -> int:
    available_days = (db.query(Table.id, Table.day)
                      .order_by(desc(Table.day))
                      .limit(100).all())
    close_dates = pd.DataFrame(available_days)
    close_dates['delta'] = close_dates['day'] - given_date
    past_dates = (close_dates
                  .loc[close_dates['delta'] < pd.Timedelta(0, unit='d')])
    table_id = int(past_dates.loc[past_dates['delta'].idxmax()]['id'])
    return table_id
```

This is not a solution that I would recommend when you have to convert in bulk. It is rather generic and expensive as you are not using joins. Moreover, it assumes that you have a relevant day that is one of the 100 most recent days in the model Table. So it tackles data input that may have different dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
from business_days import business_days

def business_days(
    start_date: date, end_date: date
) -> Generator[date, None, None]:
    us_holidays = holidays.country_holidays("US")

    date_diff = end_date - start_date

    for day in range(date_diff.days + 1):
        the_date = start_date + timedelta(days=day)
        if (the_date.weekday() < 5) and (the_date not in us_holidays):
            yield the_date

for business_days in business_days(date(2023, 7, 1), date(2023, 9,1)):
   print(business_days())
```

use DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1); and the solution above