# Computing date range in Python using pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a data set below. I want to compute the date range between today and the date below for each row value.

```
date          stock_ticker   holding_days #today-date
2014-12-17    600268         
2015-01-21    002428
2014-11-19    600031
2015-02-26    600216
2014-12-20    601682
```

I know the datetime module can do this thing but I don't know how to sign value to each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting something like this:

```
In [294]:

df['holding_days'] = dt.datetime.now().date() - df['date']
df
Out[294]:
        date  stock_ticker  holding_days
0 2014-12-17        600268       77 days
1 2015-01-21          2428       42 days
2 2014-11-19        600031      105 days
3 2015-02-26        600216        6 days
4 2014-12-20        601682       74 days

In [323]:

def func(x):
    return len(pd.bdate_range(x['date'], dt.datetime.now().date()))

df['holding_bus_days'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
df
Out[323]:
        date  stock_ticker  holding_days  holding_bus_days
0 2014-12-17        600268       77 days                56
1 2015-01-21          2428       42 days                31
2 2014-11-19        600031      105 days                76
3 2015-02-26        600216        6 days                 5
4 2014-12-20        601682       74 days                53
```

Comment: What if I just want the business days to be computed?

Comment: I found a method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703436/counting-the-business-days-between-two-series and updated my answer