# Python / Pandas / Numpy - Direct calculation of number of business days between two dates excluding holidays

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Is there a better / more direct way to calculate this than the following?

```py
# 1. Set up the start and end date for which you want to calculate the      
# number of business days excluding holidays.

start_date = '01JAN1986'
end_date = '31DEC1987'
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d%b%Y')
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%d%b%Y')

# 2. Generate a list of holidays over this period
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
calendar = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = calendar.holidays(start_date, end_date)
holidays
```

Which gives a pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex

```py
DatetimeIndex(['1986-01-01', '1986-01-20', '1986-02-17', '1986-05-26',
           '1986-07-04', '1986-09-01', '1986-10-13', '1986-11-11',
           '1986-11-27', '1986-12-25', '1987-01-01', '1987-01-19',
           '1987-02-16', '1987-05-25', '1987-07-03', '1987-09-07',
           '1987-10-12', '1987-11-11', '1987-11-26', '1987-12-25'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

But you need a list for numpy busday_count

```py
holiday_date_list = holidays.date.tolist()
```

Then with and without the holidays you get:

```py
np.busday_count(start_date.date(), end_date.date()) 
>>> 521

np.busday_count(start_date.date(), end_date.date(), holidays = holiday_date_list)
>>> 501
```

There are some other questions slightly similar but generally working with pandas Series or Dataframes ([Get business days between start and end date using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019719/get-business-days-between-start-and-end-date-using-pandas), [Counting the business days between two series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703436/counting-the-business-days-between-two-series))

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.  Are you looking for a way that is better performance-wise?  Or like one that only uses the standard library or what?

Comment: Performance isn't an issue but I just thought I was going around the houses a little bit to get the result and perhaps it might be doable directly with Pandas or Numpy, or something else ...

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  The calendar implementation is straight forward (import the module, create a USFederalHolidayCalendar object. and then calculate holidays between the start and end dates).  Seems like half of your code above is initializing and converting the start and end dates.

Comment: Sorry if the questions not clear, any suggested edits welcome. Perhaps it is better posed as 'How to calculate the number of business days between two datetimes excluding holidays using Pandas?'. Although I didn't want to limit it to Pandas directly. If this is the most direct way then fair enough - just thought there might be a neater way.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the index you created in a dataframe, you can use [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling) to fill in the gaps. The offset passed to `.resample()` can include things like business days and even (custom) calendars:

```py
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

C = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

start_date = '01JAN1986'
end_date = '31DEC1987'

(
pd.DataFrame(index=pd.to_datetime([start_date, end_date]))
    .resample(C, closed='right') 
    .asfreq()
    .index  
    .size
) - 1
```

The size of the index - 1 then gives us the amount of days.