# How to calculate a timeoffset in specific terms (like business days) between two date/datetime in python (pandas)?

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

pandas has DataOffset type of objects like `BDay` to represent business days, and if I add up a datetime , e.g. `date(2009,1,1)+BDay(9)`, I get `Timestamp('2009-01-14 00:00:00)`. How can I do the other side of the calculation, say like `GetBusinessDaysInBetween(date(2009,1,1),date(2009,1,14)` and get business days?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get business days between start and end date using pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019719/get-business-days-between-start-and-end-date-using-pandas)

Comment: I checked the post you mentioned, I actually want a direct calculation and re_index pandas using relative days, not re-align data frequency. The answer to the question didn't archive that.

Answer (score 0):

How about just generating the range and taking the length?  If you need another offset, you can obviously just use `date_range` and specific the offset.

```
len(pd.bdate_range(date(2009,1,1), date(2009,1,14)))
```