# python pandas: offset Timestamp by business day

Tags: python, pandas

The [DateOffset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) seems to be the way to go, but I'm confused with the documentation. How can I offset by business days?

Thanks.

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019719/get-business-days-between-start-and-end-date-using-pandas

Answer (score 7):

```
import datetime as dt
from pandas.datetools import BDay

ts = pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime.now())
>>> ts + BDay(5)

Out[42]: Timestamp('2015-03-24 06:48:50.133321')
```

Comment: I cannot make the import above, but this works now: `from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay`