# Python add int to a date and only return weekdays date ignoring weekends

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start_Date': ['2018-08-23', '2018-08-16', '2018-08-24', '2018-08-29'], 'Days': ['3', '1', '3', '0']})
```

I would like to create a new column "End_Date". End_Date will be Start_Date + Days. also, End_Date should be only weekdays (exclude weekend).

Expected out

```
Start Date      Days   End_Date
2018-08-23      3      2018-08-28    
2018-08-16      1      2018-08-17
2018-08-24      3      2018-08-29
2018-08-29      0      2018-08-29
```

I have tried to use the solution from [omz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691551/add-n-business-days-to-a-given-date-ignoring-holidays-and-weekends-in-python) but it is not working for me. I have tried using workday function but this is also not working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BDay](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) in this way:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date']  = df.apply(lambda x: x['Start_Date'] + BDay(x['Days']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Days Start_Date   End_Date
0     3 2018-08-23 2018-08-28
1     1 2018-08-16 2018-08-17
2     3 2018-08-24 2018-08-29
3     0 2018-08-29 2018-08-29
```

Comment: Thank you...this give me the exact results I need.

Comment: How could I improve it if i would like to have holidays excluded as well?

Comment: For the holidays it is a bit more complicated because from countries to countries they are different. If is the `USFederalHolidayCalendar` you can take a look to tihs answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822697/business-days-between-two-dates-excluding-holidays-in-python or if it is just for a couple of years you can set your holidays yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828008/adding-holidays-to-usfederalholidaycalendar

Comment: Can you post the df in a new questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.busday_offset` to get the next business day.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: df['End_Date'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.busday_offset(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   Start_Date Days   End_Date
0  2018-08-23    3 2018-08-28
1  2018-08-16    1 2018-08-17
2  2018-08-24    3 2018-08-29
3  2018-08-29    0 2018-08-29
```