# Python pandas - resample every 2nd row rather than every 2nd business day

Tags: python, pandas, resampling, datetimeindex

I am working with stock price data and would like to get `resample()` to return every 2nd row rather than every 2nd business day (`resample('2B')`). The obstacle is any holiday that lands on a weekday. See below, MLK Day is Monday, Jan 15, 2018:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
date,price
2018-01-08,88.28
2018-01-09,88.22
2018-01-10,87.82
2018-01-11,88.08
2018-01-12,89.6
2018-01-16,88.35
2018-01-17,90.14
2018-01-18,90.1
2018-01-19,90.0
2018-01-22,91.61
2018-01-23,91.9
2018-01-24,91.82
2018-01-25,92.33
2018-01-26,94.06'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, parse_dates=['date'], index_col=[0])

df_resample = df.resample('2B').min()
print(df_resample)
```

Output:

```
            price
2018-01-08  88.22
2018-01-10  87.82
2018-01-12  89.60
2018-01-16  88.35
2018-01-18  90.00
2018-01-22  91.61
2018-01-24  91.82
2018-01-26  94.06
```

I'd like the resample to jump from 1/12 to 1/17. I know that I can use `df['price'].loc[::2]` to deliver `df.resample('2B').last()` but I need to use `min()`, `max()` and `sum()` as well.

Thanks.

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: `df.loc[::2]` was my first thought, can you explain why that wont work for this dataset please? `min`, `max`, etc. should all work fine if you slice the frame

Comment: My thought is to redefine the Business days somehow. Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094297/create-trading-holiday-calendar-with-pandas

Comment: Haleemur - How would you return the 2 day minimum (every 2nd row) using `.loc[::2]` ?

Comment: @MJS, thanks for updating the question with sample data, it is clearer now what you are trying to achieve. as an aside, when responding to comments you can mention the user you are addressing using `@username`. otherwise, the user is not notified of comment activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a stable solution I'd have a look at redifining the B-days somehow.

But if you reset index you could use the index numbers and groupby:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df_resample = df.groupby(df.index // 2).min()
print(df_resample)
```

Returns:

```
        date  price
0 2018-01-08  88.22
1 2018-01-10  87.82
2 2018-01-12  88.35
3 2018-01-17  90.10
4 2018-01-19  90.00
5 2018-01-23  91.82
6 2018-01-25  92.33
```

---

**Or** you could do something like this:

```
g = np.arange(len(df))// 2
df_resample = df.groupby(g).agg(['last','min','max','sum'])
df_resample.insert(0, 'Date', df.index[1::2])

print(df_resample)
```

Returns:

```
        Date  price                      
               last    min    max     sum
0 2018-01-09  88.22  88.22  88.28  176.50
1 2018-01-11  88.08  87.82  88.08  175.90
2 2018-01-16  88.35  88.35  89.60  177.95
3 2018-01-18  90.10  90.10  90.14  180.24
4 2018-01-22  91.61  90.00  91.61  181.61
5 2018-01-24  91.82  91.82  91.90  183.72
6 2018-01-26  94.06  92.33  94.06  186.39
```

Comment: interesting Anton - in your first solution, I see that `.min()` begins on 1/8 whereas `.last()` and `.max()` begin on 1/9. In a perfect world, they would all begin and end on the same days.

Comment: Max returns the max for date too. Have a look at my alternative.

Comment: thanks. 2nd solution - I am trying to figure out how to key off the 2nd row and look backwards, rather than looking fwd (on 1/8 we're identifying the min from today and the next day, 1/8-1/9).

Comment: I pasted in an Excel snapshot. Thank you so much for working with me on this.

Comment: @MJS in that case just take the 2nd element with `[1::2]`, right? See my update.

Comment: ugh, yes - I was fumbling around with shift(). Thank you again, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

using np.repeat with array slicing, you can create a resampled dataframe where the date (index) is repeated twice.

```
df_resample = df.set_index(np.repeat(df.index[::2],2)[:len(df)])
# outputs:
            price
date
2018-01-08  88.28
2018-01-08  88.22
2018-01-10  87.82
2018-01-10  88.08
2018-01-12  89.60
2018-01-12  88.35
2018-01-17  90.14
2018-01-17  90.10
2018-01-19  90.00
2018-01-19  91.61
2018-01-23  91.90
2018-01-23  91.82
2018-01-25  92.33
2018-01-25  94.06
```

Then grouping as usual yields the desired output:

```
df_resampled.groupby(level=0).agg(['last', 'min', 'max', 'sum'])

            price
             last    min    max     sum
date
2018-01-08  88.22  88.22  88.28  176.50
2018-01-10  88.08  87.82  88.08  175.90
2018-01-12  88.35  88.35  89.60  177.95
2018-01-17  90.10  90.10  90.14  180.24
2018-01-19  91.61  90.00  91.61  181.61
2018-01-23  91.82  91.82  91.90  183.72
2018-01-25  94.06  92.33  94.06  186.39
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may also work, kind of reversing the steps...

```
df['price'].rolling(window=2).max().iloc[1::2]
```