# TypeError with asfreq(BDay()).count -- Using all column data?

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to find the count of of business days in a range.  So here's what I've got

```
df['ENTRYDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ENTRYDATE'], errors='coerce')
df['REQDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['REQDATE'], errors='coerce')
df['DELDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DELDATE'], errors='coerce')
df['SHIPCONFIRMED'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SHIPCONFIRMED'], errors='coerce')
#df['DAYSLATE'] = df['DELDATE'] - df['REQDATE']
req_date = df['REQDATE']
del_date = df['DELDATE']
df['DAYSLATE'] = df.ix[req_date:del_date].asfreq(BDay()).count()
```

But I'm getting a `TypeError` it looks like it's reading in the entire column instead of working with just the data in that row.

`TypeError: '['2017-05-26T00:00:00.000000000' '2017-05-04T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2017-05-22T00:00:00.000000000' '2017-05-12T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2017-05-12T00:00:00.000000000' '2017-05-16T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2017-04-27T00:00:00.000000000' '2017-05-26T00:00:00.000000000' ...
  ... '2017-05-18T00:00:00.000000000' '2017-05-29T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2017-05-02T00:00:00.000000000' '2017-05-02T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2017-05-17T00:00:00.000000000' '2017-04-28T00:00:00.000000000']' is an invalid key`

Any assistance or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking exactly?  you have `req_date = df['REQDATE']` so yes it's a column.  Maybe you meant to do something like `df['DAYSLATE'] = df.DELDATE - df.REQDATE` and then count if value is positive?  One way or the other it looks like you have mixed up columns and scalars (?)

Comment: @JohnE I originally had `df['DAYSLATE'] = df.DELDATE - df.REQDATE` but that doesn't take business days into account.  I am trying to count the business days between the Req Date and the Del Date.  Thanks!  also changing to `df.DELDATE` and `df.REQDATE` yielded the same error.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019719/get-business-days-between-start-and-end-date-using-pandas You're trying to copy the first answer there but as I noted above, you're filling in with columns of dates rather than scalar (single values of) dates.  I don't have time to work on this now, but the 2nd & 3rd answers there may be easier for you to implement with an apply.