# Which row is extra in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two `dataframes` that are contain market daily end of day data. They are supposed to contain identical starting dates and ending dates and number of rows, but when I print the `len` of each, one is bigger by one than the other:

```
DF1
            close
date              
2008-01-01   45.92
2008-01-02   45.16
2008-01-03   45.33
2008-01-04   42.09
2008-01-07   46.98
...
[2870 rows x 1 columns]

DF2

             close
date              
2008-01-01   60.48
2008-01-02   59.71
2008-01-03   58.43
2008-01-04   56.64
2008-01-07   56.98
...
[2871 rows x 1 columns]
```

How can I show which row either:

- has a duplicate row,
- or has an extra date

so that I can delete the [probable] weekend/holiday date row that is in `DF2` but not in `DF1`?

I have tried things like:

```
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset='date', keep='first')
df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset='date', keep='first')
```

but can't get it to work [`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`].

**Extra:**

How do I remove weekend dates from a dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May using `.loc`

```
DF2=DF2.loc[DF1.index]
```

If check index different between DF1 and DF2

```
DF2.index.difference(DF1.index)
```

Check whether DF2 have duplicate index

```
DF2[DF2.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Check the weekends

```
df.index.weekday_name.isin(['Sunday','Saturday'])
```

---

Fix your code

```
df1 = df1.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='date', keep='first').reset_index('date')
df2 = df2.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='date', keep='first').reset_index('date')
```

Also for this I recommend `duplicated`

```
df2 =df2 [df2.index.duplicated()]
```

About the `business`

```
def B_day(date):
    return bool(len(pd.bdate_range(date, date)))

df.index.map(B_day)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. It turns out there is a weekend date in there. If you feel up to it, see edited post for "extra".

Comment: @Ivan you mean the error ? I think I just fixed it .

Comment: the problem is that I don't necessarily want to drop _any_ date. First, I want to see if the data contains a row with a  date that is a weekend date. If that solves, the problem, then probably stop. If not, then go on to remove duplicate dates. Data cleaning is hard...

Comment: @Ivan if that still dose not address your problem , you may want to check B-day https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019719/get-business-days-between-start-and-end-date-using-pandas

Comment: @Ivan you can also create a date_range to find any dates that fall outside your date range and also those that are not a business day: `df2[~df2.index.isin(pd.date_range(start, end, freq='B'))]`

Comment: Thanks Chris that is useful. I am actually surprised no one has built a library for market data "cleaning".