# Difference between datetimes in terms of number of business days using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

Is there a (more) convenient/efficient method to calculate the number of business days between to dates using pandas?

I could do

```py
len(pd.bdate_range(start='2018-12-03',end='2018-12-14'))-1 # minus one only if end date is a business day
```

but for longer distances between the start and end day this seems rather inefficient.

There are a couple of suggestion how to use the `BDay` offset object, but they all seem to refer to the creation of dateranges or something similar.

I am thinking more in terms of a Timedelta object that is represented in business-days.

Say I have two series,`s1` and `s2`, containing datetimes. If pandas had something along the lines of

```py
s1.dt.subtract(s2,freq='B') 
# giving a new series containing timedeltas where the number of days calculated
# use business days only
```

would be nice.

(numpy has a `busday_count()` method. But I would not want to convert my pandas Timestamps to numpy, as this can get messy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`np.busday_count`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) here is good idea, also convert to numpy arrays is not necessary:

```
s1 = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='05/01/2019',end='05/10/2019'))
s2 = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='05/04/2019',periods=10, freq='5d'))

s = pd.Series([np.busday_count(a, b) for a, b in zip(s1, s2)])
print (s)
0     3
1     5
2     7
3    10
4    14
5    17
6    19
7    23
8    25
9    27
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Tested this on broader range of dates, to make sure that there no weird timestamp conversions from pandas to numpy going on that could mess things up. Works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
from xone import calendar
def business_dates(start, end):
    us_cal = calendar.USTradingCalendar()
    kw = dict(start=start, end=end)
    return pd.bdate_range(**kw).drop(us_cal.holidays(**kw))

In [1]: business_dates(start='2018-12-20', end='2018-12-31')
Out[1]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-20', '2018-12-21', '2018-12-24', '2018-12-26',
                       '2018-12-27', '2018-12-28', '2018-12-31'],
                      dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

source [Get business days between start and end date using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019719/get-business-days-between-start-and-end-date-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

```
#create dataframes with the dates
df=pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(start='05/01/2019',end='05/31/2019')})
#check if the dates are in business days
df[df['dates'].isin(pd.bdate_range(df['dates'].get(0), df['dates'].get(len(df)-1)))]

out[]:
0   2019-05-01
1   2019-05-02
2   2019-05-03
5   2019-05-06
6   2019-05-07
7   2019-05-08
8   2019-05-09
9   2019-05-10
12  2019-05-13
13  2019-05-14
14  2019-05-15
15  2019-05-16
16  2019-05-17
19  2019-05-20
20  2019-05-21
21  2019-05-22
22  2019-05-23
23  2019-05-24
26  2019-05-27
27  2019-05-28
28  2019-05-29
29  2019-05-30
30  2019-05-31
```