# DateTime Calculation Between Two Dates, Output returns "1 Days"? What is this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have performed a simple calculation between two dates, and the return shows an output of "1 Days", or "2 Days" etc...

```
df['Days'] = df['date1'] - df['date2']

returns:
'1 Days'
'2 Days'
```

I'm not sure how to manipulate this? So if I wanted to filter the dataframe to return rows for less than 5 days? Would I convert unit into seconds/Hours and then of course I could filter, but how could I just filter according to '1 Days' output?

Comment: What are the types of `df['date1']` and `df['date2']`?

Comment: datetime64[ns],

Comment: What is the type of `df['Days']`?  I assume it is not actually a string like `'1 Days'`.

Comment: It's a timedelta[ns] variable

Comment: Presumably timedelta objects have attributes that you can filter on (day, hour, minute, second, etc.)  Have you tried doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `dt` with `days` convert to `int`

```
df['Days'] = (df['date1'] - df['date2']).dt.days
```

Then you can filter it

```
df1=df[df['Days']<5].copy()
```

Comment: Thanks, very much

Comment: Can I ask, is there a way to exclude certain days from this calculation? For instance, only return dt.days for working days (Excluding Sunday & Saturday)?

Comment: @Sam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019719/get-business-days-between-start-and-end-date-using-pandas