# Pandas function incorrect output, can't see how. oconus_days1 row = 25 should be 20, what's wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy

Code:

```
forecast ['conus_days'] = np.where(forecast['Month']==forecast["conus_mth"],
                              (forecast['Start Date'] - forecast['start_month'].apply(us_bd)),
                               0)
forecast['conus_days']=forecast['conus_days'].dt.days
forecast ['conus_days1'] = np.where(forecast['Month']==forecast["conus_mth"],
                               forecast['end_month'] - forecast['Start Date'],
                               0)
forecast['conus_days1']=forecast['conus_days1'].dt.days

forecast['oconus_days'] = np.where(forecast['Month']==forecast['oconus_mth'],
                               (forecast['End Date'] - forecast['start_month']),
                               0)
forecast['oconus_days']=forecast['oconus_days'].dt.days

forecast['oconus_days1']= np.where(forecast['Month']== forecast["oconus_mth"],
                              (forecast['end_month']- forecast['End Date'].apply(us_bd)),0)
```

Result:

```
       Name      EID  Start Date   End Date      Country  year  Month  \
0       GP        123456 2019-08-01 2020-01-03  Afghanistan  2020      1   
1       MW       3456789 2019-09-22 2020-02-16        Conus  2020      1   
2       MH        456789 2019-12-05 2020-03-12        Conus  2020      1   
3       DR        789456 2019-09-11 2020-03-04         Iraq  2020      1   
4       JR        985756 2020-01-03 2020-05-06      Germany  2020      1   

   days_in_month start_month  end_month  working_days  conus_mth  oconus_mth  \
0             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          8           1   
1             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          9           2   
2             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21         12           3   
3             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          9           3   
4             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          1           5   

   conus_days  conus_days1  oconus_days  oconus_days1  
0           0            0            2            25  
1           0            0            0             0  
2           0            0            0             0  
3           0            0            0             0  
4           1           28            0             0
```

row 0, `oconus_days1` output should be 20 and NOT 25.

using `us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())` to calculate the number of workdays between to dates excluding holidays and weekends - same as conus_days column =1, that's correct.  If you look at the function `np.where .... forecast['end_month'] - forecast['End Date'].apply(us_bd)` output should be 20.

Comment: Could you please try without pandas and where, just using `USFederalHolidayCalendar()` and your two days?

Comment: that only works when using a specified index. I need to iterate through rows and only account for rows where Month == oconus_mth

Comment: its actually the apply portion of the function that's not work for that specific row. what should I do different the apply function a few rows above works just fine.

Comment: I am not sure that the `where` is the problem. Can you add a new column and just apply the function to all fields and see if your result is as expected?

Comment: Joe, tried it and got a different error- 
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.    forecast['oconus_days1'] = (forecast['Month']==forecast['oconus_mth'],
                                   forecast['end_month'] - forecast['End Date'].apply(us_bd),
                                   0)
forecast['oconus_days1']=forecast['oconus_days1'].dt.days
print(forecast)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33480745/7919597 try it like that

Comment: Joe, I've don't that and it works. but, that only allows to to look at one row at a time and does not iterate through rows because it creates a series with index.

Comment: import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
day1 = forecast['start_month'][0]
day2 = forecast['end_month'][0]
us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
forecast['working_days'] = len(pd.pandas.date_range(start=day1,end=day2, freq=us_bd))
print(len(pd.pandas.date_range(start=day1,end=day2, freq=us_bd)))
forecast

Comment: question, ultimately why does np.where work on the first line as it should and not on the subsequent use?

Comment: The problem might be somewhere else. What was the result of the example you just did? 20? 25? Could you please instead of using only the first row iterate from 0 to 4 and compate the result to what you posted in your question? Is it the same or different?

Comment: Joe, the problem may be ASW with the CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar() module not properly counting weekend and holidays between the two daes

Comment: 1
import pandas as pd
2
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
3
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
4
us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
5
dt1 = forecast['end_month'][0]
6
dt2= forecast['End Date'][0]
7
print(len(pd.pandas.date_range(start=dt2,end=dt1, freq=us_bd)))  
8
print(forecast)
20

Comment: Please do not post code here, add it above, below your question stating "Edit: New Example" or similar.