# Pandas Get date timestamp which belong to businesshours or Businessdays

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Find out all the `Businesshours` and `BusinessDays` from the given list. I followed couple of docs about pandas offsets, but could not figure it out. [followed stackoverflow as well, here is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019719/get-business-days-between-start-and-end-date-using-pandas) but no luck.

```
>>> d = {'hours': ['2020-02-11 13:44:53', '2020-02-12 13:44:53', '2020-02-11 8:44:53', '2020-02-02 13:44:53']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
                hours
0  2020-02-11 13:44:53
1  2020-02-12 13:44:53
2   2020-02-11 8:44:53

3  2020-02-02 13:44:53
>>> y = df['hours']
>>> from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
>>> y.apply(pd.Timestamp).asfreq(BDay())
1970-01-01   NaT
Freq: B, Name: hours, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> y.apply(pd.Timestamp).asfreq(BusinessHour())
Series([], Freq: BH, Name: hours, dtype: datetime64[ns])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, you are looking for something like:

```
bh = pd.offsets.BusinessHour()   # avoid not necessary imports
y.apply(pd.Timestamp).apply(bh.rollforward)
```

The result is:

```
0   2020-02-11 13:44:53
1   2020-02-12 13:44:53
2   2020-02-11 09:00:00
3   2020-02-03 09:00:00
Name: hours, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So:

- two first *hours* have not been changed (they are within business hours).
- third (*2020-02-11 8:44:53*) has been advanced to *9:00* (start of the
  business day).
- fourth (*2020-02-02 13:44:53* on Sunday) has been advanced to the next
  day (Monday) at *9:00*.

Or, if you want **only to check** whether particulat date / hour is within
business hours, run:

```
y.apply(pd.Timestamp).apply(bh.onOffset)
```

The resutl is:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: hours, dtype: bool
```

meaning that two last date / hours are **outside** business hours.

Comment: I think `asfreq` is for set new frequency, so I think OP need set BDay or BusinessHour frequncy (for me not working)

Comment: @Valdi_Bo - Perfect  :)  `onOffset`  will do the work for me. Thank you very much. I was testing my code on Python shell, so the imported *. ;)