# Using Python to count the number of business days in a month?

Tags: python, date

I am trying to write a Python script that will calculate how many business days are in the current month. For instance if `month = August` then `businessDays = 22`.

Here is my code for discovering the month:

```
def numToMonth( num ):
   months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
   return str(months[ num - 1 ])
```

This code works fine, and I could hard code another function to match the month with how many days that month should contain...but this does not help me with business days.

Any help? I'm used to C, C++ so please don't bash my Python "skills".

Edit: I cannot install any extra libraries or modules on my machine, so please post answers using default Python modules. (Python 2.7, `datetime` etc.) Also, my PC has Windows 7 OS.

Comment: This looks like relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224742/business-days-in-python

Comment: Thanks for the link! I viewed that question, but I'm not allowed to install extra libraries on my machine. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Should your code process holidays correctly?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt, but that is not a priority. I can hard code Holidays into the code depending on the month. My workplace is UK related so their holidays are strange.

Comment: And should it calculate number of days for current year?

Comment: Ummm.. no. My code only needs to be as I posted: calculate the number of business days in the current month.

Comment: Hi @Jacob-IT. I posted a solution that uses the bash shell as called from python. Will this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your post @psny, but I am using a Windows 7 PC. Sorry for the confusion, I will re-edit my question to show this.

Comment: Did you try already that datetime() is not installed?

Comment: https://github.com/cadu-leite/networkdays does exactly that . Its updated python 3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a long-winded way, but at least it works and doesn't require anything other than the standard modules.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
holidays = {datetime.date(now.year, 8, 14)} # you can add more here
businessdays = 0
for i in range(1, 32):
    try:
        thisdate = datetime.date(now.year, now.month, i)
    except(ValueError):
        break
    if thisdate.weekday() < 5 and thisdate not in holidays: # Monday == 0, Sunday == 6 
        businessdays += 1

print businessdays
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had to modify the code a little.. (Your indentation was strange) But it works. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. In what way was my indentation strange? The code above only catches PEP8 errors for the long line and the comment style.

Comment: looks like a hack but I would have done like that :) and it works. So thanks. Small remark: why hardcoding the year? to get a budget to ask your bosses to reopen the program in 2014 for heavy maintenance ? :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre In my country (South Africa) most holidays are not on exactly specified dates every year because the date they are observed changes to the following Monday if they fall on a weekend. So I would actually imagine you will have a yearly calendar for holidays which  will be different every year. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

I would simply use built-in module [calendar](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html):

```
import calendar

weekday_count = 0
cal = calendar.Calendar()

for week in cal.monthdayscalendar(2013, 8):
    for i, day in enumerate(week):
        # not this month's day or a weekend
        if day == 0 or i >= 5:
            continue
        # or some other control if desired...
        weekday_count += 1

print weekday_count
```

that's it.

Comment: Does calendar start with Monday and not Sunday?

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add my answer.

I'm using Calendar, list comprehension, and length to count how many days is the working day a particular month.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/env python

import calendar
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

cal = calendar.Calendar()

working_days = len([x for x in cal.itermonthdays2(now.year, now.month) if x[0] !=0 and x[1] < 5])

print "Total working days this month: " + str(working_days)
```

Answer (score 1):

I stole this from Sharuzzaman's solution and added a dict for holidays and turned it into a function:

```py
import calendar
cal = calendar.Calendar()

def get_wdim(year,month):
    working_days = len([x for x in cal.itermonthdays2(year, month) if x[0] !=0 and x[1] < 5]) 
    holidays = {
        1:1,
        2:1,
        4:1,
        5:1,
        7:1,
        9:1,
        10:1,
        11:4,
        12:1
    }
    return int(working_days) - holidays.get(month,0)


wdim2022 = [get_wdim(2022,x) for x in list(range(1,13)) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** OP can't use any external libraries. Then you will have to build some tables based on [determining the day of the week from the calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Complete_table).

The formula is d + m + y + y/4 + (c mod 7), where: d is the day of the month,
m is the month's number in the months table,
y is the last two digits of the year, and
c is the century number.

It's tedious but not impossible!

**ORIG answer:** It's quite tedious to code yourself, because August 01, 2013 and August 01, 2012 are not necessarily the same day of the week. I'd start with the 'date' class in python (details [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

```
from datetime import date
datetime.date(2002, 3, 11)
t = d.timetuple()
for i in t:     
   print i
```

In particular, check out the 'datetime.weekday()' function.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple, just break it down into steps:

1. You need to be able to loop through the days in a month.
2. You need to be able to determine the day of a week that any given date falls on. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week) lists some methods.
3. Then you need only flag days of the week as business days or not.

Combine these steps and you'll have a working method.

Comment: Thanks for encouraging me to do more research, but I was looking for a method already built in to Python. If it doesn't exist, I will post whatever algorithm I create as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at `datetime.datetime.dayofweek()` but if you are not allowed to use an external library then you need to:

1. pick a date that you know the day of week of - best if it is a
   Monday
2. come up with a formulae for the number of days since then that the
   first of a given month is.
3. for each of the days in the month the (number of days since your
   day) % 7 in [5, 6] is a weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledging the OP stated external libraries could not be used, given the ranking of the question in searches (together with the fact this wasnt stated in the title), I figured I'd share a pandas solution which provides a solution spanning multiple months, with results presented in a df.

```
    import pandas as pd
    business_days = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='B')
    pd.DataFrame(index=business_days, data=[1] * len(business_days)).resample('M').sum()
```