# Group DataFrame by Business Day of Month

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I am trying to group a Pandas `DataFrame` that is indexed by date by the business day of month, approx 22/month.

I would like to return a result that contains 22 rows with mean of some value in `DataFrame.

I can by day of month but cant seem to figure out how to by business day.

Is there a function that will return the business day of month of a date?

if someone could provide a simple example that would be most appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python to count the number of business days in a month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233122/using-python-to-count-the-number-of-business-days-in-a-month)

Comment: How do you want to handle any data for a weekend? Ignore it, roll it forward to Monday, or roll it back to the preceding Friday?

Comment: Alexander the dataframe only contains data from business days, there is no weekend data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in the index (if not use 'set_index):

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('B'))
```

See [time series functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

Comment: df.groupby('B') does not work it just throws an error

Comment: Thanks for answer Stefan. What I was wanting to achieve was somthing like the following df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('B'))['Amount'].mean() to return 22 rows with the mean value for each business day of the month

Comment: You are welcome. Hope this answered your question about grouping by business day.

Answer (score 1):

I think what the question is asking is to groupby business day of month - the other answer just seems to resample the data to the nearest business day (at least for me).
This code returns a groupby object with 22 rows

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.bdate_range(start='01 Jan 2018', periods=1000))
def to_bday_of_month(dt):
    month_start = date(dt.year, dt.month, 1)
    return np.busday_count(month_start, dt)

day_of_month = [to_bday_of_month(dt) for dt in d.index.date]
d.groupby(day_of_month).mean()
```