# How to get previous date from a date without saturday,sunday and holiday?

Tags: python

Need to get previous date from given without sat, sun and holidays(table).

Leave scenerio.

```
f_date=self.get_query_argument("from_date")
date_1 = datetime.strptime(f_date,"%Y-%m-%d")
bef_date = date_1 - timedelta(days=1)
if bef_date.weekday()==5:
   prev_date = bef_date - timedelta(days=1)
elif bef_date.weekday()==6:
   prev_date = bef_date - timedelta(days=2)
else:
   prev_date =bef_date
```

I got here the previous date without saturday and sunday but dono how to get it without holiday mentioned in table.

I already referred this link but struggling to omit holiday.

Advance thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Business days in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224742/business-days-in-python)

Comment: I need to omit holiday but the above link does not resolve this issue.

Comment: The above link does have an example of removing holidays.

Comment: I think you are saying about this example but i cant understand to omit holiday list can you help me with my above example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224742/business-days-in-python

Answer (score 0):

try using "in" on your table

```
foo = [1,2,3,4,5]
2 in foo
```

returns "True"

for dates

```
d1 = (datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(1)).date()
d2 = (datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(2)).date()
d3 = (datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(3)).date()

listOfHolidays = [d1,d2,d3]

(datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(2)).date() in listOfHolidays
```