# Determine if a day is a business day in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I currently have a program setup to run two different ways. One way is to run over a specified time frame, and the other way is to run everyday. However, when I have it set to run everyday, I only want it to continue if its a business day. Now from research I've seen that you can iterate through business days using Pandas like so:

```
start = 2016-08-05
end = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

for day in pd.bdate_range(start, end):
    print str(day) + " is a business Day"
```

And this works great when I run my program over the specified period.

But when I want to have the program ran everyday, I can't quite figure out how to test one specific day for being a business day. Basically I want to do something like this:

```
start = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

if start == end:
    if not Bdate(start)
        print "Not a Business day"
```

I know I could probably setup pd.bdate_range() to do what I'm looking for, but in my opinion would be sloppy and not intuitive. I feel like there must be a simpler solution to this. Any advice?

Comment: The hardest part of the task is defining what a business day is. It might differ by country and in rare situations even by village.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Klaus D. I guess to add some details:  this program is specific to US business days. Specifically days that the market (NYSE,NASDAQ, etc) are open and the trading of stocks occur

Comment: Please check this module. It might help you. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bdateutil/0.1

Comment: So, how are these days defined? If you have the answer you just have to put it in a function.

Comment: Please check this link also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224742/business-days-in-python

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how this could ever return `False`? `if start == end:`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since `len` of `pd.bdate_range()` tells us how many business days are in the supplied range of dates, we can cast this to a `bool` to determine if a range of a single day is a business day:

```
def is_business_day(date):
    return bool(len(pd.bdate_range(date, date)))
```

Answer (score 7):

I just found a different solution to this. This might be interesting if you want to find the next business day if your date is not a business day.

```
   bdays=BDay()
   def is_business_day(date):
       return date == date + 0*bdays
```

adding `0*bdays` rolls forward on the next business day including the current one. Unfortunately, subtracting `0*bdays` does not roll backwards (at least with the pandas version I was using).

Moreover, due to this behavior, you also need to be careful since not necessarily
`0*bdays + 1*bdays != 1*bdays`

Answer (score 6):

There is builtin method to do this in pandas.

**For Pandas version <1.0**

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day, BDay
from datetime import datetime


bday=BDay()
is_business_day = bday.onOffset(datetime(2020,8,20))
```

**For Pandas version >=1.1.0** (`onOffset` is deprecated)

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day, BDay
from datetime import datetime


bday=BDay()
is_business_day = bday.is_on_offset(datetime(2020,8,20))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using at least `numpy` version 1.7.0., try [`np.is_busday()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.is_busday.html)

```
start = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

if start == end:

    # added code here
    if not np.is_busday(start):
        print("Not a Business day")
```

Answer (score 2):

for me I use an old trick from Excel:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day, BDay

def is_bday(x):
    return x == x + Day(1) - BDay(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this module - [bdateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bdateutil/0.1)

Please check the below code using above module :

```
from bdateutil import isbday
from datetime import datetime,date
now = datetime.now()
val = isbday(date(now.year, now.month, now.day))
print val
```

Please let me know if this help.