# Apply, lambda function issues

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I'm having issues with an `if` statement and return the difference between two dates using a `lambda` function with the `apply` method. `['conus_days']` returns time/days in nanoseconds when the condition is `true`. What's wrong with my code?

```py
us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

def get_conusdays(row):
   if row['Month']== row['conus_mth']:
       return forecast['Start Date'] - forecast['start_month'].apply(us_bd)
   else:
       return 0

forecast ['conus_days']= forecast.apply(lambda row: get_conusdays(row), axis=1)

print(forecast)

           Name      EID  Start Date   End Date      Country  year  Month  \
0  XX             123456 2019-08-01 2020-01-03            AF  2020      1   
1  XT.            3456789 2019-09-22 2020-02-16        Conus  2020      1   
2  MH.            456789 2019-12-05 2020-03-12        Conus   2020      1   
3  DR.            789456 2019-09-11 2020-03-04         IR     2020      1   
4  JR.            985756 2020-01-03 2020-05-06         GE     2020      1   

   days_in_month start_month  end_month  working_days  hours  conus_mth  \
0             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21    372          8   
1             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21    168          9   
2             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21    168         12   
3             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21    372          9   
4             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21    310          1   

         cd                                         conus_days  
0 -154 days                                                  0  
1 -102 days                                                  0  
2  -28 days                                                  0  
3 -113 days                                                  0  
4    1 days  [-13305600000000000 nanoseconds, -881280000000...
```

Comment: I think you could just pass `get_conusdays` to `apply` directly, like this: `forecast.apply(get_conusdays, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the return of the `get_conusdays` function is one series and one value(0).
You need to unify your return output with a series or value.

you can try like this:

#### 1. `np.where`

```py
forecast ['conus_days'] = np.where(forecast['Month']==forecast["conus_mth"],
                                   forecast['Start Date'] - forecast['start_month'].apply(us_bd),
                                   0)
```

#### added.

```py
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-03')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-20')
print(len(pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start_date,end=end_date, freq=us_bd)))

>>> 12  #skip US holidays as well as weekends
```

so,

```py
forecast ['conus_days'] = np.where(forecast['Month']==forecast["conus_mth"],
                                   forecast.apply(lambda row : len(pd.DatetimeIndex(start=row['end_moth'],end=row['End Date'], freq=us_bd)), axis=1),
                                   0)
```

same problem : [Most recent previous business day in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224742/most-recent-previous-business-day-in-python)

#### 2. apply(your method)

```py
def get_conusdays(row):
   if row['Month']== row['conus_mth']:
       return row['Start Date'] - row['start_month'].apply(us_bd)
   else:
       return 0
forecast['conus_days']= forecast.apply(lambda row: get_conusdays(row), axis=1)
```

If you don't know the `CustomBusinessDay` exactly and you don't need to apply it to the series, you should do it this way(each row).

Comment: yganalyst - in method 1 (np.where) do you know why custombusinessday does not offset weekends in certain occasions.  for example if you take the example above and replace it with forecast['end_month] - forecast['End Date'].apply(us_bd), you will get number of days between those two time periods minus the holiday but, not the weekends.  How can I correct this?

Comment: sorry for the answer is late. i was updated my answer. I hope it helps and tell me if you need more help.