# How to schedule job for last business day of month in Python APScheduler?

Tags: python, apscheduler

How would I go about scheduling a job in Python APScheduler for the last business day of the month, at 5:30pm?

For example:

1. If the last day of the month falls on a **Sunday**, I would like the job to execute on **Friday at 5:30pm**.
2. If the last day of the month falls on a **Wednesday**, I would like the job to execute that **Wednesday at 5:30pm**.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no way of APScheduler knowing what a 'business day' or 'business month' is for your specific business.  You will have to work out the next x month end dates and schedule tasks on each individual date.

Comment: First look at how you can detect and deal with business days, e.g. in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224742/most-recent-previous-business-day-in-python). Scheduling the rest is trivial.