# Max value by date given array value and array date with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, date, max

I need for each day to know what the max value of the previous day was, example:

array with dates

```
date = np.array(['05/12/2017', '05/12/2017', '05/13/2017', '05/13/2017', '05/13/2017',
 '05/13/2017', '05/14/2017', '05/15/2017', '05/15/2017', '05/15/2017',
 '05/15/2017', '05/15/2017', '05/16/2017', '05/16/2017', '05/16/2017',
 '05/16/2017', '05/16/2017' '05/16/2017', '05/17/2017', '05/17/2017'])
```

array with values:

```
value = np.array([13, 4, 5, 4, 17, 8, 5, 9, 17, 6, 11, 16, 12, 7, 7, 12, 17, 10, 16, 14])
```

result I need:

```
result = np.array([0, 0, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have a missing comma in the dates array.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import defaultdict
dates = np.array(['05/12/2017', '05/12/2017', '05/13/2017', '05/13/2017', '05/13/2017',
 '05/13/2017', '05/14/2017', '05/15/2017', '05/15/2017', '05/15/2017',
 '05/15/2017', '05/15/2017', '05/16/2017', '05/16/2017', '05/16/2017',
 '05/16/2017', '05/16/2017', '05/16/2017', '05/17/2017', '05/17/2017'])

values = np.array([13, 4, 5, 4, 17, 8, 5, 9, 17, 6, 11, 16, 12, 7, 7, 12, 17, 10, 16, 14])


parsed_dates = np.array([datetime.strptime(_, "%m/%d/%Y") for _ in dates])
dv = zip(parsed_dates, values)
max_dates = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for date, value in dv:
    max_dates[date] = max(value, max_dates[date])

one_day = timedelta(days=1)
result = np.array([max_dates[d - one_day] for d in parsed_dates])
```

Comment: that worked in a beautiful way with the example given. I am using it with intraday stock data so that I need the max value of the previous day but every n days (for example 4) it gives a day of zeros... and I cant't figure out why

Comment: okay, I figured out that this happens because my data is contained in business days only and when it subtracts a day from monday for example i get no data... any ideas on how to do max_dates[d - one_business_day] ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19036752/9039523