# How to subtract a time frequency string value ('1min') from datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

If I have a variable (in `pd.datetime` format):

```
date_value = pd.to_datetime("2019-12-10 10:57:00")
```

... how can I subtract a pandas frequency value from that datetime? For example, I may want to subtract `"1min"`, or `"15min"`, or `"1B"`, or `"1W"` from that value.

These frequency values are stored as strings, and instead of parsing each string value for the integer and time value (min, day, week, etc.) which would be annoying, I'm wondering if there's a way to utilize the freq string values directly. Pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
new_date_value = date_value - timedelta("1min")
```

...but of course `timedelta` doesn't use the freq strings. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Use `pd.Timedelta()` or `pd.to_timedelta` instead?

Comment: Pandas handles this fine `date_value - pd.Timedelta('1min')`. I'm not sure what 1B is but the rest work as is.

Comment: Didn't even know about pandas' timedelta! Thanks for the easy answer!!!

Comment: @HenryEcker `B` should be business day, as denoted here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases  HOWEVER, `Timedelta` doesn't understand it as `B` is an invalid argument as shown here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html, which SUCKS because I need BUSINESS DAY for my dataset! lol

Comment: Hm. Yeah. Offsets are different than timedeltas. Timedelta are a fixed amount of time and are reduced to numeric values for faster computation. I'm not sure you'll find timedelta support for variable ranges like business days. Naturally `date_value - pd.offsets.BDay(1)` works, but I don't know if offsets has a string parser.

Comment: I literally just saw this solution as you mentioned it haha: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19036752/10018602 In my use case, the business day is always 1 for now so I can just do an if statement that checks if the freq value has a B in it, then use this formula. Thanks again!

Comment: NP. It looks like [this is the list of supported units for timedelta](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a62897ae5f5c68360f478bbd5facea231dd55f30/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyi#L19-L61) (for reference)